# how can i find all saturdays of a month using dojo date locale

Tags: date, dojo, calendar

I have used below code to find weekends of a month.
**`isDisabledDate:dojo.date.locale.isWeekend`**

How can I determine only `"Saturday"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **dojo/date/locale** module.

```
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale){
    var dateFormat = locale.format(new Date(),{
    selector: "date",
    datePattern:"EEEE"
    });
    if (dateFormat === 'Saturday') {
       alert('It is a Saturday');
    }
});
```

Check the [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html#dojo-date-locale-format) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a JavaScript Date object, no Dojo-specific code is actually required to determine if a day of a month is a Saturday:

```js
function isSaturday(/*Date?*/dateObject){
 var day = (dateObject || new Date()).getDay();
 return day === 6;
}

console.log(isSaturday(new Date('April 2, 2015')));
console.log(isSaturday(new Date('April 4, 2015')));
```

*Note: Open the console to view results.*